# How to make sure that a checkbox appears unchecked in Tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I have a problem which looks like some kind of a bug. Sometimes it happens that a Checkbutton first appears checked when created and it seems like there is no apparent reason for this behaviour. I'm using external variables to get information about status of the checkbox and I'm sure I reset them right before the declaration. My declaration looks like this:

```
#item is a string
cbtn = Checkbutton(master, command=lambda method=item: fun(method))
```

You can see there's even no variable or state argument in the declaration, so I think this should always create an empty checkbox. Yet somehow, sometimes it appears checked at first, which is a problem because I'm creating a lock and then it looks opposite than it's supposed to.

So, is there a sureproof way to make it appear without a checkmark?

Answer (score 0):

> So, is there a sureproof way to make it appear without a checkmark?

Yes. Explicitly set the `onvalue` and `offvalue` attributes, associate a variable with the checkbutton, and explicitly set the value of the variable to the same as the `offvalue`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I decided to use a button which will change color as an indicator. Looks a bit uglier but it gets the job done and doesn't have any unexpected problems.